# QGIS Text annotations will not persist

Tags: qgis, annotation

I am suffering an ongoing issue with text annotations not persisting in a project after it has been closed and then reopened. The screen dump below shows two annotations; the one that appears as "Test 2" was created while I had the project open and displays correctly. The blue square to the left is a label that I created in a previous work session before I closed the proejct and re-opened it. Both labels appear in the annotations panel, but the missing annotation shows nothing until I click on the label in the annotations panel, at which point the blue box appears.

I have had this issue with every version of QGIS that I have used. The version here is the current 3.33 - Master.

Can this be operator error? Or do I have a bug in the system somewhere?

Thansk in advance.

[image]

[image]